# Finding a Trigonometric Form of Complex Number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I need to find the trigonometric form of the complex number: $1-i\sqrt{3}$

I found that

$r = 2$

which means the trigonometric form is $2 ( \cos \alpha - i\sin \alpha)$ and I need to find the alpha.

I know that you can find alpha by the formula:

$$\tan \alpha = b/a$$

so I got

$$\tan \alpha = -\sqrt{3}$$

but how do I continue from here in order to get alpha as $\pi$ ?

Comment: Just take the arctangent and you'll have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: $$z=a+ib=r\cos\theta+i\ r\sin\theta$$
$$\therefore\begin{cases}\cos\theta&=\dfrac{a}{r}\\\\\sin\theta&=\dfrac{b}{r}\end{cases}$$
**USEFUL**:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline\theta&0&\pi/6&\pi/4&\pi/3&\pi/2\\\hline\cos\theta&1&\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}&0\\\hline\sin\theta&0&\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}&\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}&1\\\hline \end{array}$$

Comment: that table at the end helped me eventually. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers say draw a picture but that is exactly what you should do. I wouldn't mess around with $\theta=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ as what happens when $x=0$... draw a picture.

Answer (score 0):

$$1-\sqrt{3}i=$$

$$\left|1-\sqrt{3}i\right|e^{\arg\left(1-\sqrt{3}i\right)i}=$$

$$\sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{3}^2}e^{\tan\left(\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{1}\right)i}=$$

$$\sqrt{1+3}e^{-\tan\left(\sqrt{3}\right)i}=$$

$$\sqrt{4}e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i}=$$

$$2e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i}$$

So:

$$1-\sqrt{3}i=2e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i}=2\left(\cos\left(-\frac{1}{3}\pi\right)+\sin\left(-\frac{1}{3}\pi\right)i\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

As you have $1-\sqrt{3}i$ we can see that
\begin{eqnarray}
\left|1-\sqrt{3}i\right|e^{\arg\left(1-\sqrt{3}i\right)i} &=& \sqrt{1^2+\sqrt{3}^2}e^{\tan\left(\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{1}\right)i} \\
                                                          &=&\sqrt{1+3}e^{-\tan\left(\sqrt{3}\right)i} \\
                                                          &=& \sqrt{4}e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i} \\
                                                          &=& 2e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i}
\end{eqnarray}
So to sum up

\begin{eqnarray}
1-\sqrt{3}i &=& 2e^{-\frac{1}{3}\pi i} \\
            &=& 2\left(\cos\left(-\frac{1}{3}\pi\right)+\sin\left(-\frac{1}{3}\pi\right)i\right)
\end{eqnarray}